# Beamer alignment of bullets in Itemize environment polyglossia RTL

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, itemize, polyglossia, arabic

how can I align the bullet in itemize environment in beamer presentation that uses polyglossia

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib,locale=morocco]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\usetheme{madrid}
%\usecolortheme{crane}

% for RTL liste
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTListe}{\raggedleft\rightskip\leftm}
\newcommand{\leftm}{\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

% RTL frame title
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vspace*{-1mm}
  \nointerlineskip
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=2.2em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
        \strut\hskip1ex\insertframetitle\strut
        \vskip-0.8ex%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}


% align subsection in toc
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
{\leavevmode\rightskip=5ex%
  \llap{\raise0.1ex\beamer@usesphere{subsection number projected}{bigsphere}\kern1ex}%
  \inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\makeatother

% RTL triangle for itemize
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}} 

%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\rule{4pt}{4pt}}

\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{square2}
{\LR{
    %
    \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      {\color{fg}\insertenumlabel}%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[square2]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\rightskip\rightmargin
\section{I عموميات}
\subsection{1 دالة عددية لمتغير حقيقي}

\begin{frame}{تمارين}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}\RTListe
        \item ${\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{x-3}}$
        \item ${\displaystyle  g(x)=\frac{1-2x}{x^{2}+x-6}}$
        \item ${\displaystyle h(x)=\sqrt{x-2}}$
        \item ${\displaystyle l(x)=\frac{6x-1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x-2}}}$
        \item ${\displaystyle m(x)=\sqrt{x(x-2)}}$
        \item ${\displaystyle s(x)=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1-|x|}}}$
    \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]